# Click event in Fragment leaks to the parent Activity layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding a Fragment fragment with clickable views to my Activity.

I have noticed that if I click on a point inside that Fragment which does not have any OnClickListener, the click event leaks to the layout below, in this case, the Activity layout. If there is a view with its own OnClickListener in that point, its code is executed. I can prevent this click by adding a dummy OnClickListener to the Fragment background but I want to know if there is a better option.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include some of your current code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

property to the parent view of your layout as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141855/an-invisible-layout-behind-the-fragment-is-getting-clicked) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912651/issue-in-android-fragment-still-click-on-previous-fragment).

Comment: @Juanje welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

set background color to your fragment layout and set layout width and height to match parent.
May be it will solve your problem

Comment: Changing the color is not enougth